# Involutory functions and iteration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

A function is called an involution if it is its own inverse, that is, $f^2(x)=x$. This implies that $f^3(x)=f(x), f^4(x)=x$, and in general, $f^{2k}(x)=x$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Does it follow that every function $f$ such that $f^{2k}(x)=x$ is an involution?

Comment: Is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ? Is it assumed to be continuous?

Comment: I do not put conditions on $f$; I just use the definition of an involution. But You can put conditions in your answer if you wish.

Comment: Ok! Are you asking whether $(\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) \, f^{2k}(x) \equiv x$ implies $f^2(x) \equiv x$ or do you want to classify all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{2k}(x) \equiv x$ implies $f^2(x) \equiv x$ ? (I'm using $f(x) \equiv g(x)$ to denote function equality, i.e. $(\forall x) \, f(x) = g(x)$)

Comment: To start with, it is OK to take all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ not just  all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ since for negative $k$ values it is simply the inverse which is still the original function being an involution. Now, coming to your question, I want to show that $f$ is an involution if and only if $f^{2k}(x)=x$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, for a fixed $k$, does $f^{2k}(x)=x$ imply that $f$ is an involution?

Answer (score 2):

If you can prove that $f^{2k}(x)=x$ for all integer $k$, this means that $f^{2(1)}(x)=x$ because $1$ is an integer.  Thus $f^2(x)=x$ which is the condition for it being an involution.

Comment: But you have only answered the trivial case $k=1$, I am especially looking at other values of $k$.

Comment: Of course, you could state that if $f^{2k}(x)=f^{2k-2}(f^2 (x))=f^{2k-2}(x)$ and use induction to show that this leads to what I have given above. You did state that any function s.t. $f^{2k}(x)=x$ where $k$ is an integer, which means that you know that the inductive proof is already known to be certain beforehand.

Comment: But $f(z)=iz$ is not an involution and yet $f^4(z)=z$. What's your say?

Comment: $f(z)=iz$ does not satisfy the condition you gave that $f^{2k}(x)=x$ for all integer $k$ though, because $f^2(z)=-z$.

Comment: Alright, so you mean $f$ is an involution if and only if $f^{2k}(x)=x$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Your original question was $f^{2k}(x)=x, k \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow f^{2}(x)=x$.  The converse is not always true of these statements where one truth implies another.  However, in this case, I believe it to be true, so yes.

Comment: Thanks Harry Alli